# GROUP BY messages MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I started developing chat application for my website.

First I did some javascript part, before I got to backend.
And Now just created database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_bp_my_chat` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `to` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `sent` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `recd` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `to` (`to`),
  KEY `from` (`from`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Now, having this databse, I want to make a request to see all messages grouped by "from" OR "To"

Think of it as facebook messages, when you go to actual page, there is a left sidebar with messages grouped by conversation.

the output should be like:

- conversation between "user_1" and "user_2" (unread) 2 hours ago

  conversation between "user_1" and "user_3" (unread) 3 hours ago

  converstation between "user_1" and "user_5" 5 hours ago

so my messages are grouped like conversations.
I might have 10 message from user_2 but it should be displayed as one (and info from last one)

Any Ideas how I go next?
As I have not done any php side yet You can even suggest changing database to adjast for your solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you want your output to look like? SQL's GROUP BY functionality is used to get summary statistics (e.g., the total number of messages from a particular sender), so that doesn't sound like what you want.

Comment: Are you looking for a query that will return all the messages in the proper order, or one that will just return summary information, like you showed in the update? If so then I was wrong and you do want to use GROUP BY after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you would run this for one person ('user_1') for their conversations, which means they can be either the from or the to.  I also assume that it make no difference if they are the from or the to, but to group by the other person in the conversation. If so, try this.  (You should put some sample data in SQLFiddle for testing)

```
SELECT MostRecent.MainPerson AS MainPerson
  , MostRecent.OtherPerson AS OtherPerson
  , MostRecent.Sent AS Sent
  , IF(wp_bp_my_chat.recd = 0, 'Unread','Read') AS Status
FROM wp_bp_my_chat
JOIN (
    SELECT 'user_1' AS MainPerson
       , IF(msgs.`from` = 'user_1',msgs.to, msgs.`from`) AS OtherPerson
       , MAX(msgs.sent) AS sent
    FROM wp_bp_my_chat AS msgs
    WHERE msgs.`from` = 'user_1' OR msgs.`to` = 'users_1'
    GROUP BY MainPerson, OtherPerson) AS MostRecent
  ON (wp_bp_my_chat.`from` = MostRecent.MainPerson OR wp_bp_my_chat.`to` = MostRecent.MainPerson)
    AND (wp_bp_my_chat.`from` = MostRecent.OtherPerson OR wp_bp_my_chat.`to` = MostRecent.OtherPerson)
    AND MostRecent.sent = wp_bp_my_chat.sent
ORDER BY sent DESC
```

Comment: I think this should work as you undestood my brutal question :D

Yes it does not matter if it's "from" or "To", I will run this per person and yes, I want to group them with other person.

I can't test it now already as I'm not with that computer now, but will do it tomorrow, thank you very much

Comment: Okay first I went with different answer but with more data I checked it was not working the way I wanted it to work.

I didn't chose this one because it outputed an error about unknow field.

After more investigation I changed  "IF(wp_bp_my_chat = 0, 'Unread','Read')" to  "IF(wp_bp_my_chat.recd = 0, 'Unread','Read')"
And now it works, did I do it right or it's a simple magic? )

Answer (score 0):

To get the results you described in your update, use:

```
SELECT count(*), max(sent) 
FROM wp_bp_my_chat
WHERE to = 'name of recipient'
GROUP BY from
```

`count(*)` gives you the number of messages and `max(sent)` gives you the time of the latest message, which you can use to calculate the "hours ago" part of the output.

I don't see a flag in your table for whether the message has been read. You'd need to add that in order to add the "(unread)" text.

Comment: whats the flag? :D I'll use boolean expression to see if it's read or not.

Comment: anyways, what If it was me who initiated this message?

Comment: Do you use facebook? If yes, you can go https://www.facebook.com/messages and see left sidebar, that's what I'm talking about, except I don't want to display message itself, only information like read/unread timeago

Comment: Then this solution will work for you. Also, why would it matter if you initiated the message?

Comment: it does not matter, but consider this.
I send a message (I'm from and user_3 is to)  and I didn't got any answer. Will it still output this as conversation?

Comment: Yes, it will output that as a conversation.

Comment: I accept your answer because it's looks more simple when it does the same thing + you answered first ))

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with a simple group by query:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_bp_my_chat` WHERE `to` = {my_id} GROUP BY `from`
```

This will give you all the chats that I as a user have had.

Comment: what if it was me who intiated this message?

Comment: I think best is to have a separate table which stores all initiated conversations. Thus you will only need to query that table. And store the messages in another table. Which will be linked with the id

Comment: I need both sent and recived in one query organized by conversations